# How can I switch the default binding on IIS 7.5 programatically without it shutting down?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

We have a fleet of IIS 7.5 servers that manage our hosted product.  Each generation of the product gets its own AppPool and its own site.  Every generation is bound to thegeneration.oursite.com, plus one lucky website gets the default binding (which is the one customers actually hit, obviously).  When we are ready to switch to the new site, we have a tool that attempts to switch the default binding from the old generation to the new one.  The pattern for this is:

1. Clear the bindings on all websites.
2. Reestablish the custom bindings on all websites
3. Set the default binding to the new active generation.

So far, so good.  Our code to do this is simple and works great.

Well, almost.  Here's the thing: no matter what we do, no matter how we try to structure things, *IIS always shuts down the new default binding,* complaining that there are now two sites with default bindings.  This happens no matter whether we use the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly or edit `applicationHost.config`.  Notably, manually starting the site after the conflict warning works great, 100% of the time, and neither `applicationHost.config` nor the assembly interface actually show two sites with the default binding at any point.

How can we keep IIS 7.5 from shutting down when we swap default bindings? Is there really no way to do this?

**EDIT**: I was asked to clarify what I meant wth an example, so I'll walk through an actual upgrade of one project we're managing this way, Kiln.

So let's say we start off with two generations of Kiln that are active: `Kiln1.0` and `Kiln2.0`. This means I have AppPools with those names and sites with those names.  Basically customers are on `Kiln1.0`; only our testers and beta users are on `Kiln2.0`.  Kiln accounts belong to subdomains, so to achieve this, the `Kiln2.0` site has bindings for e.g. `*:80:foo.kilnhg.com`, `*:80:bar.kilnhg.com`, etc., and `Kiln1.0` site has the binding `*:80:*` so that anyone who's not explicitly on the testing generation is on the new generation.

When we want to upgrade everyone to `Kiln2.0`, we want to delete the `*:80:*` binding on `Kiln1.0` and create it on `Kiln2.0`.  The issue I'm having is that *every single way to do that shuts down `Kiln2.0`*, with IIS claiming that the binding is duplicated.  It's that particular binding that's causing the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "Default Binding", a binding is just a binding. Can you add to your question a worked example of what you're doing?

Comment: Sure; I gave a concrete (albeit simplified) example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be a victim of IIS configuration update latency.

Typically, this can be avoided by either reducing the number of steps (eg, why clear then re-establish bindings? Just replace them in one go then commit the change), or adding wait states.

Yes, wait states. {Sleep 10 seconds} in the middle of the batch file/script/program would probably get it working too.